# How to apply effect of scrolling text on image Like in Airbnb App?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I want to achieve effect of scrolling text on an image like in the Airbnb app. The effect shows an image view on top of text. When scrolling up, the text will slowly shrink. When scrolling down, the text enlarges again.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can check these libraries: https://github.com/zhigang1992/ZGExpandZoomView and https://github.com/quemb/QMBParallaxScrollViewController and https://github.com/modocache/MDCParallaxView

Comment: Is there a screenshot we can see?

Comment: @YoCoh thanks for your response, it looks something helpful.

Comment: @MattZanchelli  I don't have screen shot only this Airbnb app for reference.

Comment: @Vishal'sp I was hoping to see screenshots of the app you're referring to. I'm not sure where in the app this occurs.